# Best practice for delivering SFTP key to client?

Tags: sftp

We are rolling out a solution that is going to leverage SFTP, we have hundreds of sites we want to deploy this to.  The solution is basically a windows service that is using an installer, so it's a bit challenging to deliver the key in a secure manner.  We have a client facing website where we plan to allow clients to get the installer from.

Ideally we want to have the installer or service get the key itself, but I can't think of a way to make this secure.  The SFTP key is from our *nix server, so I can generate them easily.  its just the delivery which I have an issue with.  One thing I was thinking of is a REST call on service steartup, taking the client ID as a paramter, and delivering the SFTP key as call output.  The service would then create the key in the file system.

Any ideas?

Comment: To be clear, this is not enterprise management, these would all be separate domains that don't talk to each other, and the only foot print we want to have is our config file and service.

Comment: In terms of key management, the "best practice" would really be: You don't distribute the private key, you don't even have the private key, they send you their public key. So; in your case, you can have the installer generate the public/private keypair and somehow get that into your system. You're still left with a problem of authentication, which you likely cannot do securely, portable and/or unattended. If you'd be OK with an attended install, make the installer prompt them to log on at which point the public key can be transferred to you and tied to their account(s).